# C# SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery returning -1 for successful UPDATE SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

The following code, using `.ExecuteNonQuery`, appears to work:

```
public static void StringQueryWithParameterList(
    string queryString,
    List<string> keys,
    List<string> values
)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString);
    int affected;

    command.Connection = GetConnection();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++) {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
    affected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();  // Note: this is returning -1 ... why?

    if (affected < 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("No rows were updated by this update query.");
    }
}
```

`.ExecuteNonQuery` is returning `-1` for a reason I don't understand.  I have observed that this function does work, the database is being updated as expected when I check in SQL Server Management Studio.  Obviously I want to use the return value I'm expecting from `.ExecuteNonQuery` to verify that a row was successfully changed, but this is not working.

I investigated the MSDN docs for `.ExecuteNonQuery` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)).  The docs report that a `-1` result is expected for the following scenarios:

- For all SQL statement types **other than** UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE (but mine is an UPDATE)
- If no statements are detected that contribute to the count (but I'm seeing the database is updated as expected, so this doesn't make sense to me)
- If a rollback occurs (obviously not, as a I see my changes in the database)

For transparency's sake, here is the query I'm using:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_col = 2 WHERE my_id = 'some_id';
```

Comment: `AddWithValue(keys[i], values[i])` is not type safe. I dont advice using it.

Comment: It will also return -1 if the `SET NOCOUNT ON;`  was previously executed on the session or set at the server level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `SET NOCOUNT` is `ON` at instance level.

To check it you can use `DBCC USEROPTIONS;`

In order to `SET NOCOUNT OFF`, you can

```
sp_configure 'user options' 0
```

**PS:** `AddWithValue(keys[i], values[i])` is not type safe. I don't advise using it.

Comment: `NOCOUNT` was the culprit, thank you.  We will take `.Parameters.Add(...)` as an alternative under consideration.  Very helpful!